# Error Using std::vector<std::string> myString

Tags: c++, string, vector

Hi it's a little bit hard for me to understand what the compiler is saying:

> [BCC32 Error] frmNew.cpp(333): E2285 Could not find a match for 'std::getline<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>(ifstream,std::vectorstd::string,std::allocator<std::string >)'
> Full parser context
> frmNew.cpp(303): parsing: void _fastcall TFrmNewPeta::showDefaultRute()

I'm using `std::vector<std::string>mystring` to store my strings file, but
`while (std::getline(ifs_Awal, mystring))` throws the error.

This is my complete code:

```cpp
    void __fastcall TFrmNewPeta::showDefaultRute()
    {
        std::string mystring;
        std::ifstream ifs_Awal;
        int tempIndexAwal = 0;
        ifs_Awal.open("DefaultDataAwal");
        while (std::getline(ifs_Awal, mystring)) {++tempIndexAwal;}
        std::vector<std::string> mystring(tempIndexAwal);
        while (std::getline(ifs_Awal, mystring)) // error
        {
            mystring.push_back(mystring); // error
        }
        ifs_Awal.close();
    }
```

I'm using C++ Builder 2010.

In many tutorials they prefer to using `std::vector` to store a string to a dynamic array. So I did the same thing, but the error occurred when I tried using `std::vector<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

billz and tomi rights your passing wrong argument so I change your code. should be

```
    void __fastcall TFrmNewPeta::showDefaultRute() {
    std::string lines;
    std::ifstream ifs_Awal;
    int tempIndexAwal = 0;
    ifs_Awal.open("DefaultDataAwal");

    /*get the strings and counting the lines*/
    while(std::getline(ifs_Awal,lines)){++tempIndexAwal;}

    std::vector<std::string> mystring(tempIndexAwal);

    while(std::getline(ifs_Awal,lines)) //put your 'lines' here
    {
        mystring.push_back(lines); // theres no error again :)
    }
    ifs_Awal.close();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for change my code to be the correct answer. I've been do  the same way as you answer. thanks

Comment: I'm so glad if that's you want. also you can use the members functions of the vector `at()` to shown the element. example `std::cout<<mystring.at(0)<<endl;`

Answer (score 3):

second parameter of [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) could be `std::string` but not `std::vector<std::string>`. It's quite clear as error message shows.

update

```
std::vector<std::string> mystring(tempIndexAwal);
```

to:

```
std::string mystring;
```

You do not post how you declare `myline`, I suppose it's `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your passing wrong argument to `getline`.

`mystring` is not a `std::string` as it should be, but a `std::vector`. Thus line
`std::getline(ifs_Awal,mystring)` causes an error since the second argument is not `std::string`.

Also, line

`myline.push_back(mystring)`

does not work because `myline` is probably a vector of string, and you try to push an element of `vector<string>` to it.

So, as suggested already, changing `myline` to `std::string` is the answer.

Comment: Hi @Tomi.lee.jones, I realize I'm wrong declare using mystring as string to use as vector. so I change my code as you suggest and its works, Thanks for your advice